# Updating a specific word in a column

Tags: postgresql

How could I update the St. to Street on this column? I am getting a hard time on how to figure this out

| Address |
| --- |
| 125 Center St, New York City, NY 10001 |
| 68 Hickory St, Seattle, WA 98101 |

I am trying to update one word on a column which is the St. to Street

Answer (score 1):

I would use an expression like

```
regexp_replace(col, '\mSt\M\.?', 'Street', 'g')
```

Comment: Oh sorry for that. But I think you know what I mean hehe